# File not found error while uploading audio file from android client to server

Tags: android, servlets, client-server, filenotfoundexception

I tried uploading an audio file from android client to server but I'm getting following error on server console:
java.io.FileNotFoundException:D:\temp\sdcard\recording20605.3gpp (The system cannot find the path specified) 
("D:\temp" is where I'm trying to store file from client on my server i.e in temp folder in D drive of my pc).

Plz help

### Here is the code for Client and server

### SERVER CODE

```
    // Import required java libraries
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

    public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

       private boolean isMultipart;
       private String filePath;
       private int maxFileSize = 9000 * 1024;
       private int maxMemSize = 6 * 1024;
       private File file ;

       public void init( ){
          // Get the file location where it would be stored.
          filePath = 
                 getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload"); 
       }
       public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response)
                  throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
          // Check that we have a file upload request
          isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
          response.setContentType("text/html");
          java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
          if( !isMultipart ){
             out.println("<html>");
             out.println("<head>");
             out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
             out.println("</head>");
             out.println("<body>");
             out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
             out.println("</body>");
             out.println("</html>");
             return;
          }
          DiskFileItemFactory factory = new 

DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("D:\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

      try{ 
      // Parse the request to get file items.
      List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

      // Process the uploaded file items
      Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      while ( i.hasNext () ) 
      {
         FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
         if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
         {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            String fileName = fi.getName();
            String contentType = fi.getContentType();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
            // Write the file
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }else{
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
            }
            fi.write( file ) ;
            out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
         }
      }
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
   }catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
   }
   }
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                       HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

        throw new ServletException("GET method used with " +
                getClass( ).getName( )+": POST method required.");
   } 
}
------------------
CLIENT CODE
-----------------
package com.client;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

    public class SampleclientActivity extends Activity {     
        private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 2;
        String selectedPath = "";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            openGalleryAudio();
        }

        public void openGalleryAudio(){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), SELECT_AUDIO);
       }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                if (requestCode == SELECT_AUDIO)
                {
                    System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO");
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO Path : " + selectedPath);
                    doFileUpload();
                }

            }
        }

        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } 

        private void doFileUpload(){
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream inStream = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 4*1024*1024;
            String responseFromServer = "";
            String urlString = "http://123.236.177.244:8085/myproject1/UploadServlet";
            try
            {
             //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
             // open a URL connection to the Servlet
             URL url = new URL(urlString);
             // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             // Allow Inputs
             conn.setDoInput(true);
             // Allow Outputs
             conn.setDoOutput(true);
             // Don't use a cached copy.
             conn.setUseCaches(false);
             // Use a post method.
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
             dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             // create a buffer of maximum size
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
             // read file and write it into form...
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
             while (bytesRead > 0)
             {
              dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
             }
             // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
             // close streams
             Log.e("Debug","File is written");
             fileInputStream.close();
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex)
            {
                 Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                 Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
            //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
            try {
                  inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
                  String str;

                  while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
                  {
                       Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
                  }
                  inStream.close();

            }
            catch (IOException ioex){
                 Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }
          }
}
----------------------
AndroidManifest.xml
---------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.client"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA"></uses-permission>


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SampleclientActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filename contains an extra "\sdcard" which is trying to save the file in "sdcard" directory inside the "temp" directory. Ofcourse SDCARD is the directory not found on server so it is throwing exception. Either change the file name on runtime and remove "sdcard" from it or create the directory named "sdcard" inside "temp".

Answer (score 1):

solution is:

```
private String filePath = "---your directory---"

private String filePath = "D:\temp\sdcard\"
```